# In Interview, I asked to write constructor, Copy constructor and assignment operator

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

In Interview, I asked to write constructor, Copy constructor and assignment operator. I wrote the following code.

He then asked me what is wrong in following code which I unable to answer, could you help me to know what is wrong?

Also, From question what interviewer was trying to find?

```
//constructor, copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor

class Employee
{
    int id;
    char *name;
public:
    //constructor
    Employee()
    {
        id=0;
        *name = new char[];
    }
    
    //Copy constructor
    Employee (const Employee& oldObj)
    {
        id = oldObj.id;
        *name = *(oldObj.name);
    }
    
    //destructor
    ~Employee()
    {
        delete[] name;
    }
    
    //Assignment operator overloading
    void operator = (const Employee& obj)
    {
        id = obj.id;
        delete[] name;
        *name = *(obj.name);
    }
    
};


int main()
{
    Employee a1;
    Employee a2 = a1; //copy constructor
    
    Employee a3;
    a3 = a1;//assignment operator
}
```

Comment: The copy constructor copies one char only and dereferences uninitialised pointer. The operator attempts to copy one char only to the deleted memory. The declaration of the operator does not allow sequenced assignments like `a = b = c;`. The default constructor fails to compile.

Comment: `new char[]` is invalid as well - either you need just one char (`new char;` or `new char()`), but then you need to `delete name` – or you need to specify an array size (as you always seem to use just one character then `new char[1]`) – for a first try, later on you'll likely want to have longer arrays...

Comment: Assignment shouldn't `delete[]`: You are just copying a single character, but where would you copy it to if the array was deleted before? (Note: later on you *will* delete, but not as is now, just copying the single character).

Comment: Minor issue: You should use the constructors' initialiser lists (not to be confused with `std::initializer_list`): `Employee() : id(0), name(new char[1]) {}` Similarly copy constructor, but you still need to assign the single character – this favours direct initialisation over default initialisation + assignment, the latter could have significant overhead if complex classes are involved. Be aware, too, that some types *only* can be initialised that way (references, `const` members, non-default-constructible types).

Comment: Note, too, that using `char*` is for *learning* purposes, later on you'd most likely be using `std::string` instead; with that one all of default copy/move constructor/assignment and destructor would be totally fine already...

Comment: rewrite your code and correct some error for it. https://godbolt.org/z/5GoWT7fsM

Comment: You need to study the fundamentals about pointers and dynamic memory in your favourite C++ book.

Answer (score 0):

> what is wrong in following code

- Using bare owning pointers instead of smart pointers or containers.
- `*name = pointer` is ill-formed.
- `new char[]` is ill-formed.